# selective building of new dataframe with existing dataframes in addition to calculation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, merge

Fill in the Pandas code below to create a new DataFrame, customer_spend, that contains the following columns in this order: customer_id, name, and total_spend. total_spend is a new column containing the sum of the cost of all the orders that a particular customer placed.

I'm doing an online course related to Python Pandas. As I wrote above, the goal of this code is making a new dataframe called 'customer_spend', with columns of customer_id, name, and total_spend.

What I'm having a trouble is that building a dataframe with only portion of two different, existing dataframes. I tried merge but it takes every column of existing dataframes. In addition, I'm having difficulty with re-naming the column to 'total_spend'.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

customers = pd.DataFrame([[100, 'Prometheus Barwis', 'prometheus.barwis@me.com',
    '(533) 072-2779'],[101, 'Alain Hennesey', 'alain.hennesey@facebook.com',
    '(942) 208-8460'],[102, 'Chao Peachy', 'chao.peachy@me.com',
    '(510) 121-0098'],[103, 'Somtochukwu Mouritsen',
    'somtochukwu.mouritsen@me.com','(669) 504-8080'],[104,
    'Elisabeth Berry', 'elisabeth.berry@facebook.com','(802) 973-8267']],
    columns = ['customer_id', 'name', 'email', 'phone'])
orders = pd.DataFrame([[1000, 100, 144.82], [1001, 100, 140.93],
   [1002, 102, 104.26], [1003, 100, 194.6 ], [1004, 100, 307.72],
   [1005, 101,  36.69], [1006, 104,  39.59], [1007, 104, 430.94],
   [1008, 103,  31.4 ], [1009, 104, 180.69], [1010, 102, 383.35],
   [1011, 101, 256.2 ], [1012, 103, 930.56], [1013, 100, 423.77],
   [1014, 101, 309.53], [1015, 102, 299.19]],
   columns = ['order_id', 'customer_id', 'order_total'])

combined = pd.merge(customers,orders, on='customer_id')
grouped = combined.groupby('customer_id')['order_total']
grouped.aggregate(np.sum).reset_index()
```

desired result: dataframe named 'customer_spend' with columns of customer_id, name, and total_spend. total_spend is a new column containing the sum of order_total.

what I've got so far: only customer_id and order_total.

I'm still new to this community. If I'm doing something inappropriate, please let me know.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider first aggregating `orders` by `customer_id`, then merging the resulting `customer_id`-indexed DataFrame onto the desired columns of `customers`:

```
cust2spend = orders.groupby('customer_id').sum()[['order_total']].reset_index()
cust2spend
customer_id     order_total
        100         1211.84
        101          602.42
        102          786.80
        103          961.96
        104          651.22

# Before merging, rename the order_total column to total_spend.
# Note that axis=1 could also be axis='columns'.
cust2spend.rename({'order_total': 'total_spend'}, axis=1, inplace=True)

pd.merge(customers[['customer_id', 'name']], cust2spend, on='customer_id')
   customer_id                   name  total_spend
0          100      Prometheus Barwis      1211.84
1          101         Alain Hennesey       602.42
2          102            Chao Peachy       786.80
3          103  Somtochukwu Mouritsen       961.96
4          104        Elisabeth Berry       651.22
```

Comment: Thanks for comment Peter. I tried your method and understood that it is a correct answer. However, seems like the answer submission page doesn't take my answer. Would it be ok to show you the error message?

Comment: Sure! Sounds like the online course is expecting a specific approach, but there are many ways of doing this.

Comment: True. I've experienced this type of issue several times - but this time, error message is to eloquent. Here is the link to error. thank you for help!

https://www.evernote.com/shard/s424/sh/678912d7-675f-4b2e-8ed5-a1b6b7014f79/5da4a8713616e033c1b9b9fc3636c374

Comment: I'm not sure if this is useful at this point, but here is the hint message.
Hint: The column you groupby is not included as a column in the output DataFrame, but as its index. If you then try to merge on that column (which isn't there), Pandas looks for it and can't find it. A handy way to get around this type of problem is the .reset_index() method, which was mentioned towards the end of Pandas Lesson 4 on split-apply-combine.

Comment: @DanielKim, odd, in my testing with pandas 0.23.4, `pd.merge` handles a named index perfectly well. My guess is this online course was designed around an earlier version of pandas. Try this: `cust2spend = orders.groupby('customer_id').sum()[['order_total']].reset_index()`, followed by the rest of my answer.

Comment: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s424/sh/759a0903-02ca-49b6-9e66-5bd3e1049b45/f44e63d8475a82129f55e89a50658e8a
@peter-leimbigler
I tried it but this time code doesn't work at all (even online submission did not take the answer, your code without .reset_index() worked to produce dataframe.) 
Here is the error message

Comment: @DanielKim, ah sorry, I forgot to modify the column-renaming line! Let me edit the answer to accurately match what I think should work.

Comment: no worries at all. I really appreciate your support! Because of this online submission, I could not finish the program but you helped me to move on.

Comment: This is really unfortunate. It completely works on my Jupyter notebook but online submission still says error. I guess I need to contact technical support team instead.
Sorry :( but thank you so much for your support.

Comment: @DanielKim, that's frustrating... I hope you get an answer from them! At least you know how to get the correct result now :)

Comment: thank you Peter. FYI, this was the error message I got from this submission page:
TypeError: rename() got an unexpected keyword argument "axis"

Answer (score 0):

```
#Sorting so that data are consistent
customers = customers.sort_values(by = 'customer_id', ascending=True)

# Creating an empty DataFrame
customer_spend = pd.DataFrame(columns= 'customer_id,name,total_spend'.split(','))

#Filling columns details
customer_spend[['customer_id', 'name']] = customers[['customer_id', 'name']]
customer_spend['total_spend'] = orders.groupby('customer_id').sum().sort_values(by='customer_id', ascending=True)['order_total'].tolist()
```

If using merge is not mandatory try this.