# Merging DataFrames in Pandas and Numpy

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have two different data frames pertaining to sales analytics. I would like to merge them together to make a new data frame with the columns customer_id, name, and total_spend. The two data frames are as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

customers = pd.DataFrame([[100, 'Prometheus Barwis', 'prometheus.barwis@me.com',
        '(533) 072-2779'],[101, 'Alain Hennesey', 'alain.hennesey@facebook.com',
        '(942) 208-8460'],[102, 'Chao Peachy', 'chao.peachy@me.com',
        '(510) 121-0098'],[103, 'Somtochukwu Mouritsen',
        'somtochukwu.mouritsen@me.com','(669) 504-8080'],[104,
        'Elisabeth Berry', 'elisabeth.berry@facebook.com','(802) 973-8267']],
        columns = ['customer_id', 'name', 'email', 'phone'])

orders = pd.DataFrame([[1000, 100, 144.82], [1001, 100, 140.93],
       [1002, 102, 104.26], [1003, 100, 194.6 ], [1004, 100, 307.72],
       [1005, 101,  36.69], [1006, 104,  39.59], [1007, 104, 430.94],
       [1008, 103,  31.4 ], [1009, 104, 180.69], [1010, 102, 383.35],
       [1011, 101, 256.2 ], [1012, 103, 930.56], [1013, 100, 423.77],
       [1014, 101, 309.53], [1015, 102, 299.19]],
       columns = ['order_id', 'customer_id', 'order_total'])
```

When I group by customer_id and order_id I get the following table:

```
customer_id  order_id  order_total

100           1000       144.82
              1001       140.93
              1003       194.60
              1004       307.72
              1013       423.77
101           1005       36.69
              1011       256.20
              1014       309.53
102           1002       104.26
              1010       383.35
              1015       299.19
103           1008       31.40
              1012       930.56
104           1006       39.59
              1007       430.94
              1009       180.69
```

This is where I get stuck. I do not know how to sum up all of the orders for each customer_id in order to make a total_spent column. If anyone knows of a way to do this it would be much appreciated!

Comment: It seems like you're grouping by one more level than necessary - how are you doing that? What are you ultimately after though? Is it something like: `customers['total_spend'] = customers['customer_id'].map(orders.groupby('customer_id')['order_total'].sum())` ?

Comment: I got the above table by doing ```customer_spend = pd.merge(customers, orders)

customer_spend.groupby(["customer_id", 'order_id']).sum()``` Ultimately I am after a final table that will give me the customer_id, name, and how much that person spent all together (hence the new total_spend column)

Comment: and does the above not do that?

Comment: Your question and answer is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54066263/selective-building-of-new-dataframe-with-existing-dataframes-in-addition-to-calc/54070696)

Comment: what is your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can do something like below

```
orders.groupby('customer_id')['order_total'].sum().reset_index(name='Customer_Total')
```

**Output**

```
customer_id     Customer_Total
0   100     1211.84
1   101     602.42
2   102     786.80
3   103     961.96
4   104     651.22
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an additional table then `merge` back to your current output.

```
# group by customer id and order id to match your current output
df = orders.groupby(['customer_id', 'order_id']).sum()

# create a new lookup table called total by customer
totalbycust = orders.groupby('customer_id').sum()
totalbycust = totalbycust.reset_index()

# only keep the columsn you want
totalbycust = totalbycust[['customer_id', 'order_total']]

# merge bcak to your current table 
df =df.merge(totalbycust, left_on='customer_id', right_on='customer_id')
df = df.rename(columns = {"order_total_x": "order_total", "order_total_y": "order_amount_by_cust"})

# expect output
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
df_merge = customers.merge(orders, how='left', left_on='customer_id', right_on='customer_id').filter(['customer_id','name','order_total'])
df_merge = df_merge.groupby(['customer_id','name']).sum()
df_merge = df_merge.rename(columns={'order_total':'total_spend'})
df_merge.sort_values(['total_spend'], ascending=False)
```

Results in:

```
                                    total_spend
customer_id name    
100         Prometheus Barwis       1211.84
103         Somtochukwu Mouritsen   961.96
102         Chao Peachy             786.80
104         Elisabeth Berry         651.22
101         Alain Hennesey          602.42
```

A step-by-step explanation:

1. Start by merging your *orders* table onto your *customers* table using a left join. For this you will need pandas' [`.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) method. Be sure to set the `how` argument to *left* because the default merge type is *inner* (which would ignore customers with no orders).

   > This step requires some basic understanding of SQL-style merge methods. You can find a good visual overview of the various merge types in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101).
2. You can append your merge with the [`.filter()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) method to only keep your columns of interest (in your case: *customer_id*, *name* and *order_total*).
3. Now that you have your merged table, we still need to sum up all the *order_total* values per customer. To achieve this we need to group all non-numeric columns using [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and then apply an aggregation method on the remaining numeric columns ([`.sum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) in this case).

   > The `.groupby()` documentation link above provides some more examples on this. It is also worth knowing that this is a pattern referred to as "split-apply-combine" in the pandas documentation.
4. Next you will need to rename your numeric column from *order_total* to *total_spend* using the [`.rename()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) method and setting its `column` argument.
5. And last, but not least, sort your customers by your *total_spend* column using [`.sort_values()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html).

I hope that helps.